# Creating a Where Clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

```
find_by_sql("SELECT s.productcode, s.description, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount FROM softwares s LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id GROUP BY s.productcode, s.description WHERE s.supplier= 'softcat'")
```

I currently have this, and i get the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SoftwaresController#export_softcat`

I'm trying to add a where clause on the end to only select the records with a certain supplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.productcode, s.description, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
FROM softwares s
    LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
WHERE s.supplier = 'softcat'
GROUP BY s.productcode, s.description
```

Try it this way

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have the `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY` clause, effectively changing the SQL to be:

```
SELECT s.productcode, s.description, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
FROM softwares s 
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
WHERE s.supplier= 'softcat'
GROUP BY s.productcode, s.description
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the GROUP BY statement after the WHERE clause statement